# Embeddable entity with @OneToMany attribute

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Say, I have following entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Embedded
  private B b;

  //getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class B {
  @OneToMany
  private List<C> cList;
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class C {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Using schema-autogeneration feature with `Hibernate` I get an additional table which contains mappings between `A` and `C`. But I'd like to implement a one-to-many relationship by adding `A`'s *id* into `C` (*e.g without additional table*).

Is this possible? If yes, what annotations should I use to create such a mapping?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general that is possible with [@JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) annotation. It works also with embeddables.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
private List<C> cList;
```

If you are not happy with A_ID name for column given in embeddable, you can override column name in entity A:

```
@AssociationOverride(name= "cList",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="SOME_NAME_FOR_JOIN_COLUMN_IN_TABLE_C"))
@Embedded
private B b;
```

Comment: But how do I specify, that `A_ID` is the identifier of entity `A`?

Comment: You do not have to specify that, mappings given in B are evaluated in the context of A and that's why your persistence provider knows it. Or maybe you mean how to override join column name - I added example to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked for me. I thought I needed to explicitly tell the persistence provider what entity to get the `id` from, but it turned out to be a little smarter :)