# Hibernate @OneToMany inside @Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have the following scenario:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<B> setOfB;
}

@Embeddable
class B{
    @OneToMany
    private Set<C> setOfC;
}

@Entity
class C{
    private String name;
}
```

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878066/embeddable-entity-with-onetomany-attribute) looks like this is doable, however I am getting the following errors. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: A_setOfB, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(setOfB.setOfC)]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible in Hibernate according to their manual at [7.2.3. Collections of basic types and embeddable objects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues).

> But you are not limited to basic types, the collection type can be any embeddable object. To override the columns of the embeddable object in the collection table, use the @AttributeOverride annotation.

```
@Entity
public class User {
   [...]
   public String getLastname() { ...}

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Addresses", joinColumns=@JoinColumn    (name="user_id"))
   @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name="street1", column=@Column(name="fld_street"))
   })
   public Set<Address> getAddresses() { ... } 
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    public String getStreet1() {...}
    [...]
}
```

> **Such an embeddable object cannot contains a collection itself.**